# How do i import html files into Vue files

Tags: html, vue.js, import

I have a few html files that contains a few charts that i must show in mu vue page.
However when i try to import them i get the following error:

```
./src/components/graphs/myHtml_js.html 2:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| 
> <!doctype html>
| <html lang="en">
| <head>
```

I tried using v-html and [this solution](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/html-import-both-internal-and-external-html-files-in-vue-js/47688) but the same error is shown.

This is how i tries to import it:

```
<template>
<v-main>
    <v-container>
        <v-row align='center' justify="center">
            <v-col
            class="d-flex justify-center"
            cols="6"
            >
                <v-card
                class="mx-auto"
                width="100%"
                min-height="200px"
                outlined
                >
                <htmlImport />
                </v-card>
            </v-col>
        </v-row>                 
    </v-container>
</v-main>
</template>

<script>
import { htmlImport } from '@/components/graphs/myHtml_js.html'

export default {
    component: {
        htmlImport
    },
  data: () => ({
      
  }),
  methods: {
      
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: You need to add html-loader in your webpack/vue config. Then you will be able to import html as a variable. https://webpack.js.org/loaders/html-loader/

Comment: Or you can fetch your html (with axios for example) and then use the response as you like